# angularjs filter from array that contains object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-filters

This might be simple but i am not sure how to go about it.
I have created two scope array(not sure if required in controller) and my actual list in controller

```
$scope.tagFilter = [{tag_id:1,tag_name:test},{tag_id:2,tag_name:test2}];
$scope.categoryFilter = [{cat_id:1,cat_name:test3},{cat_id:2,cat_name:test4}]
```

my actual list

```
$scope.list = [{list_id:1,category_id:1,tag:1},...]
```

Is it possible to create a filter where i can compare tag_id with tag in list and cat_id with category_id
I was thinking of creating angular.module.filter but not really sure how to do it

Answer (score 1):

You can write a `filter` function which behaves in the following way:

```
var allowed_tags = $scope.tagFilter.map(function(item){
    return item.tag_id;
})

var allowed_cat = $scope.categoryFilter.map(function(item){
    return item.cat_id;
})

var filtered = $scope.list.filter(function(i){
return ((allowed_tags.indexOf(i.tag) != -1) && 
        (allowed_cat.indexOf(i.category_id) != -1));
})

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: i am very new to angularjs so this is kind of throwing me off. I understand what you are trying to do but can you please tell me how .map works,does it match item with tag_id with each object, and where exactly will i be placing this code. Does this go in controllers?